# If we take a adiabatic closed container and allow CaO and water to mix. Will reaction take place? will entropy of system change?

Tags: thermodynamics

my attempt. If reaction takes place then it releases energy (exothermic) which will increase temperature inside the container this implies internal energy of container increases but because heat exchanged this zero and work done is also zero by first law of thermodynamics    change in internal energy is also zero. this contradicts that reaction takes place. So can we say that in any adiabatic process in closed container change in entropy is zero.

Comment: The internal energy may change when work or heat in exchanged with the environment. But it can also change if a chemical reaction happens, like here.

Answer (score 0):

Internal energy remains constant in isolated systems.

Chemical energy released/consumed by rearranging of chemical bonds during chemical reactions transforms usually to/from thermal energy, leading to temperature changes.

Entropy of isolated systems during spontaneous processes increases.